# SQL: Select data from two tables that are related by a third

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have three tables as such:

```
Table Relations(buyerID INTEGER, sellerID INTEGER)
buyerID and sellerID are foreign keys

+---------+---------+
| buyerID | sellerID|
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       3 |
|       2 |       3 |
|       3 |       2 |
|       4 |       1 |
|       5 |       2 |
+---------+---------+

Table Buyers(ID INTEGER, name VARCHAR(30), phone VARCHAR(10))
ID is a primary key
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID | name  | phone        |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 | Eric  | 9872554-1260 |
|  2 | Julia | 897-953-3210 |
|  3 | Josh  | 999-123-3250 |
|  4 | Martha| 098-213-8270 |
|  5 | Jill  | 909-457-3990 |
+----+-------+--------------+

Table Sellers (ID INTEGER, name VARCHAR(30), phone VARCHAR(10))


+---------+----------+--------------+
| ID      | name     | phone        |
+---------+----------+--------------+
|       1 | Nathan   | 321-45-6789  |
|       2 | Rob      | 112-22-3463  |
|       3 | Maria    | 404-040-0804 |
|       4 | Logan    | 305-954-7781 |
|       5 | Smith    | 810-123-5556 |
+---------+----------+--------------+
```

I need to use the Relations table to print out SellerID,buyerID pairs, sorted by agent name. Basically, going through the Relations table, picking each seller ID starting with the first one, and printing that along with all of its associated buyers before going on to the next seller.
The output should look like this:

```
+---------+------------+
|  Seller |    Buyer   |
+---------+------------+
|Maria    |   Eric     |
|Maria    |   Julia    |
|Nathan   |   Martha   |
|Rob      |   Josh     |
|Rob      |   Jill     |
+---------+------------+
```

The statement I am currently using looks like this:

```
SELECT s.name,b.name FROM Seller s, Buyers b
INNER JOIN Relations r ON (r.sellerID = s.ID )
ORDER BY s.name;
```

However, this is giving a "Unknown column "r.sellerID in 'on clause' " error
I know that I am misusing joins somehow, but I'm now exactly sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated

Comment: using `comma` join would confuse beginners how this works.. i suggest use the new method which is explicitly using the `JOIN` type with the `on clause` as required... what you have done their is a mixture of both and obviously missing the `join fields` for `sellers` and `buyers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT
    b.name AS Seller,
    s.name AS Buyer
FROM
    Relations r
LEFT JOIN
    Buyers b
ON
    r.buyerID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN
    Sellers s
ON
    r.sellerID = s.ID
GROUP BY
    b.name,
    s.name
ORDER BY
    b.name,
    s.name
```

Answer (score 1):

To get **exactly** the output you are after, you can use this query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf3184/7)). Note it has a weird `ORDER BY` clause as sorting by b.name changes the order of the last two entries (those matched to Seller Rob) relative to what you want. You should probably just use b.name instead of b.id though.

```
SELECT s.name AS Seller, b.name AS Buyer
FROM Relations r
JOIN Sellers s
ON r.sellerID = s.ID
JOIN Buyers b
ON r.buyerID = b.ID
ORDER BY s.name, b.id
```

Output:

```
Seller  Buyer
Maria   Eric
Maria   Julia
Nathan  Martha
Rob     Josh
Rob     Jill
```